# C++ multiple definition linker error from optimization level

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

To start with I understand that there are several multiple definition error questions here, but I'm getting stumped by this.

I have a module that I'm developing and I've been building in debug i.e. `-DDEBUG -g -O0`. Now that I want to make a release `-DNDEBUG -Os` I build and I get linker errors for multiple definitions of several STL definitions including

- std::basic_ios >::basic_ios()
- std::__throw_bad_alloc()
- std::string::assign(char const*)v
- etcetera

I have checked my project, all header files have #ifndef guards and the only code in header files is declared inline.

In messing around I find that I can compile with `-DNDEBUG -O0`, but not with any level of optimization.  The build process involves building about 2 dozen object then linking them together.  Why would optimization kill the linker?  and how can I fix this?

Building with TDM MinGW 4.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also replicates when including MFC debug files in release mode or vice-versa. *It can* be the same issue here - this is just a wild guess.

To solve what I'm guessing is the cause, do the following:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
//include files that give you multiple definitions here
#endif

//.....
//.....
//rest of code/includes

#ifdef DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#undef DEBUG_WAS_DEFINED
#define _DEBUG  //revert to previous state
#endif
```

You might want to take a look at this link: http://www.flounder.com/debug_release.htm, the section about Mixed DLL's.

Comment: Like I said in the question I can't find what the problem files are.  Any help to figure out what files are the problem children?

Comment: @AndrewRedd are you including any MFC headers? You can of course try to remove files until you find the source.

Comment: I don't think that the mixed dll problem has anything to do with this.   I'm building completely from clean, and not mixing debug and release.

Comment: I believe that there are some, buried in some included headers.  Is there a way to know for sure?

Comment: I think I found the offending file.  It also included windows.h but I still do not understand why optimization would trigger this or how to get around it.

Comment: @AndrewRedd different names for when DEBUG or _DEBUG or whatever is defined in the libraries. Have you tried what I suggested?